# DI Using An External DLL

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I have two completely independent web application that each use a shared core dll.  For deployment and versioning purposes I'd like to be able to deploy a single copy of the "core" dll for both apps to use.  I'd also like to be able to support, if needed, the ability to substitute the core DLL at deployment as an option.  In other words, app1 could use core dll version 1, and app2 could use core dll version 2.  Is there a DI container that will support resolving implementation classes in a single DLL by path to support these features?  IOW, app1 would grab it's implementation classes from c:\corev1\core.dll, and app2 would grab it's implementation classes from c:\corev2\core.dll as a simple example?  I need to avoid direct references to core.dll due to our deployment strategy where all applications are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need DI or a container to do this. [Assembly Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is supported by .NET out of the box.

Just deploy the core.dll alongside the rest of your application binaries for each application and version them independently of each other.

Comment: This is a good suggestion and valid for the over-simplified scenario I gave.  MEF has solved the issue for me and allowed me to avoid direct references to the dll as states in the problem.  Our development process and our current CI process needs some work, and we're eventually headed in that direction to use a simplified approach, but we just can't right now.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want pluggability, not necessarily (or in addition to) DI.  Take a look at [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).